# train loss not decreasing(convert pytorch code to tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, loss

I am training a model with roberta using transformers, and the train loss did not decrease after a few steps, I can not find out the reason, any suggestions will be thankful.

here is the model:

```
class TriggerExtractor(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 bert_dir,
                 dropout_prob=0.1,
                 use_distant_trigger=True,
                 **kwargs):
        super(TriggerExtractor, self).__init__()

        config_path = os.path.join(bert_dir, 'config.json')
        assert os.path.exists(bert_dir) and os.path.exists(config_path), 'pretrained bert file does not exist'
        self.bert_module = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(bert_dir)
        self.bert_config = self.bert_module.config

        self.use_distant_trigger = use_distant_trigger
        out_dims = self.bert_config.hidden_size

        if use_distant_trigger:
            embedding_dim = kwargs.pop('embedding_dims', 256)
            self.distant_trigger_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=3, output_dim=embedding_dim, embeddings_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal)
            out_dims += embedding_dim

        mid_linear_dims = kwargs.pop('mid_linear_dims', 128)

        self.mid_linear = keras.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Dense(mid_linear_dims, input_shape=(out_dims,), activation=None),
            keras.layers.ReLU(),
            keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_prob)
        ])

        self.classifier = keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(mid_linear_dims, ), activation=None)
        self.criterion = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

    def call(self, inputs):
        # print('inputs:', inputs)
        token_ids = inputs['token_ids']
        attention_masks = inputs['attention_masks']
        token_type_ids = inputs['token_type_ids']
        distant_trigger = inputs['distant_trigger']
        labels = inputs['labels']

        bert_outputs = self.bert_module(
            input_ids=token_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_masks,
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids
        )

        seq_out = bert_outputs[0]

        if self.use_distant_trigger:
            assert distant_trigger is not None, \
                'When using distant trigger features, distant trigger should be implemented'

            distant_trigger_feature = self.distant_trigger_embedding(distant_trigger)
            seq_out = keras.layers.concatenate([seq_out, distant_trigger_feature], axis=-1)

        seq_out = self.mid_linear(seq_out)
        logits = keras.activations.sigmoid(self.classifier(seq_out))

        out = (logits,)
        if labels is not None:
            labels = tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.float32)
            loss = self.criterion(logits, labels)
            out = (loss,) + out
        return out
```

here is the train code:

```
train_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_dataset.__dict__).shuffle(10000).batch(opt.train_batch_size)

    for epoch in range(opt.train_epochs):
        for step, batch_data in enumerate(train_loader):

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                loss = model(batch_data)

            grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.variables)

            # for (grad, var) in zip(grads, model.variables):
            #     if grad is not None:
            #         name = var.name
            #         space = name.split('/')
            #         if space[0] == 'tf_bert_model':
            #             optimizer_bert.apply_gradients([(tf.clip_by_norm(grad, opt.max_grad_norm), var)])
            #         else:
            #             optimizer_other.apply_gradients([(tf.clip_by_norm(grad, opt.max_grad_norm), var)])


            optimizer.apply_gradients([
                (tf.clip_by_norm(grad, opt.max_grad_norm), var)
                for (grad, var) in zip(grads, model.variables)
                if grad is not None
            ])

            global_step += 1
            if global_step % log_loss_steps == 0:
                avg_loss /= log_loss_steps
                logger.info('epoch:%d Step: %d / %d ----> total loss: %.5f' % (epoch, global_step, t_total, avg_loss))
                avg_loss = 0.
            else:
                avg_loss += loss[0]
```

here is the result:

```
07/13/2021 20:09:22 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   ***** Running training *****
07/13/2021 20:09:22 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -     Num Epochs = 10
07/13/2021 20:09:22 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -     Total training batch size = 8
07/13/2021 20:09:22 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -     Total optimization steps = 3070
07/13/2021 20:09:22 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   Save model in 307 steps; Eval model in 307 steps
07/13/2021 20:09:36 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 20 / 3070 ----> total loss: 1.73774
07/13/2021 20:09:50 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 40 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04631
07/13/2021 20:10:03 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 60 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04586
07/13/2021 20:10:17 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 80 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04734
07/13/2021 20:10:31 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 100 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04554
07/13/2021 20:10:44 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 120 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04733
07/13/2021 20:10:58 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 140 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04613
07/13/2021 20:11:12 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 160 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04643
07/13/2021 20:11:26 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 180 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04613
07/13/2021 20:11:39 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 200 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04643
07/13/2021 20:11:53 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 220 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04553
07/13/2021 20:12:07 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 240 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04582
07/13/2021 20:12:21 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 260 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04642
07/13/2021 20:12:35 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 280 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04582
07/13/2021 20:12:48 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:0 Step: 300 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04672
07/13/2021 20:12:53 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   Saving model & optimizer & scheduler checkpoint to ./out/final/trigger/roberta_wwm_distant_trigger_pgd/checkpoint-307
07/13/2021 20:13:05 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 320 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04582
07/13/2021 20:13:18 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 340 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04552
07/13/2021 20:13:32 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 360 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04672
07/13/2021 20:13:46 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 380 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04762
07/13/2021 20:13:59 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 400 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04642
07/13/2021 20:14:13 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 420 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04612
07/13/2021 20:14:27 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 440 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04582
07/13/2021 20:14:41 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 460 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04702
07/13/2021 20:14:54 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 480 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04672
07/13/2021 20:15:08 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 500 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04672
07/13/2021 20:15:22 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 520 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04552
07/13/2021 20:15:36 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 540 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04552
07/13/2021 20:15:49 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 560 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04672
07/13/2021 20:16:03 - INFO - src_final.utils.trainer -   epoch:1 Step: 580 / 3070 ----> total loss: 0.04552
```

PS: I am converting the pytorch code to tensorflow for some reason, the pytorch version is all right(https://github.com/WuHuRestaurant/xf_event_extraction2020Top1). thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason. it's the position between 'y_pred' and 'y_true'. there is diffrence between pytorch and tensorflow